# Is there a trope for cowboys who laugh after punching something?

Tags: trope, western

In Overwatch and Mortal Kombat X, there are two characters, one is Mcree, and the other is Erron Black. Both are themed and designed to be your stereotypical cowboy.

However, I have been looking for what may be a trope but I am not sure where it may have originated, or even if it exists.  Basically, after they use their fists in a move to beat something or someone up, they will give a short laugh afterwards, either a snicker, or a smug sort of laugh.

Because both of these characters are from entirely different games and franchises and yet are both themed after the stereotypical cowboy this leads me to wonder if this is some sort of trope in cowboy movies?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BoisterousBruiser or maybe http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BloodKnight but most cowboys are depicted as. .. cowboys. Shoot first shoot second punch happy idiots.

Comment: Also,  rephrase your question to be about movie characters or get closed. One example is Owen Wilson on night at the museum and shanghai nights